# how to get rid of duplicate values in array and display only unique ones

Tags: php

So I have this array :

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "Air France"
    [124]=>
    string(15) "British Airways"
    [292]=>
    string(7) "easyJet"
}
```

but if i make a foreach for every value it will print out all the flights that have that name and i only want to print the name just once it has been encountered in the array;

Something like :

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($airlines)) {
    array_push($unique_airports,$value["OutboundAirlineName"]);

    $really_unique = array_unique($unique_airports);    
    foreach($really_unique as $key=>$value) {
        echo $value.'<br />';
    }
}
```

and i want the output to be :

Air France
British Airways
easyJet

Comment: Please try a `print_r($unique_airports);` - do you have a single array or a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: well this is the print_r :

Array
(
    [0] => Air France
)
Air France
Array
(
    [0] => Air France
    [1] => Air France
)
Air France
Array
(
    [0] => Air France
    [1] => Air France
    [2] => Air France
)
Air France
Array
(
    [0] => Air France
    [1] => Air France
    [2] => Air France
    [3] => Air France
)
Air France
Array
(
    [0] => Air France
    [1] => Air France
    [2] => Air France
    [3] => Air France
    [4] => Air France
)

and it keeps going like that

Comment: As expected this is a multi-dimensional array and then `array_unique` is no good. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `foreach` out from the loop which builds the array.
Do something like this:

```
while(list($key, $value) = each($airlines)) {
    array_push($unique_airports,$value["OutboundAirlineName"]);
}

$really_unique = array_unique($unique_airports);    
foreach($really_unique as $key=>$value) {
    echo $value.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: OMFG, man I will call you my saviour from now on ! this dose the trick perfect ! and you sir just made my day, thank you very much !

Comment: ofc, just had to wait 3 minutes :D, it worked like a charm dear sir

Answer (score 1):

use the internal function `array_unique` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: I have used it but with no succes, updated my question